# How do I create customized fixed-width column/x-label?

Tags: core-plot, scatter-plot

**Goal:** to produce fixed-width columns of months per data.

**Problem:** column width varies per #data points.  Hence, some labels cluster together

 (e.g., 'JanFeb' vs 'Jan....Feb') due to lack of data for a particular month.

The following code snippet creates new labels/month but has no control of statically placing labels across the x-axis; so some labels may merge if few data items exist for that particular month (fewer points):

```
    for (PerformanceDataItem *item in perfDataArray) {
    if (![item.month isEqualToString:currentMonth]) {
        currentMonth = item.month;
        CPTAxisLabel *newLabel = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:item.month textStyle:x.labelTextStyle];
        newLabel.tickLocation = [[NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:index] decimalValue];
        newLabel.offset = 2;
        [customLabels addObject:newLabel];
        [newLabel release]; 
    }
    ++index;    
} // end for().

x.axisLineStyle = nil;
x.majorTickLineStyle = nil;
x.minorTickLineStyle = nil;
x.labelingPolicy =  CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;


NSSet* customlabelSet = [NSSet setWithArray:customLabels];
x.axisLabels = customlabelSet;
```

**Question:** How can I create a customized fixed-width set of columns to plot the data?

...merely setting x.labelingPolicy to

```
CPTAxisLabelingPolicyFixedInterval
```

clutters the x-axis with a lot of numerals (1.0 - x.0) vs using my own NSString labels.

**Also tried:**
a) altering the plotSpace.xRange; and
b) altering the x.majorIntervalLength.

**Preference:** custom-label for: `CPTAxisLabelingPolicyFixedInterval`

P.S. I'm assuming that widening the thin columns (with fewer data) would merely plot an extrapolation to the next data point of the following month; without need to fill in any missing data points to equal a neighboring-month's set of points.

============================

Solution based on comment:

> plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromUnsignedInteger(0)
>   length:CPTDecimalFromUnsignedInteger(100)];
>
> axisFixedInterval.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromDouble(25.0);
>       NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
>
> ```
> // Set begining date to April 1, 2012:
> [dateComponents setMonth:4];
> [dateComponents setDay:1];
> [dateComponents setYear:2012];
> [dateComponents setHour:0];
> [dateComponents setMinute:0];
> [dateComponents setSecond:0];
> NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
> NSDate *refDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents:dateComponents];
> [dateComponents release];
> [gregorian release];
>
> NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
> dateFormatter.dateStyle = kCFDateFormatterMediumStyle;
> [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM"];
>
>
> CPTCalendarFormatter *calFormatter = [[[CPTCalendarFormatter alloc] initWithDateFormatter:dateFormatter] autorelease];
> calFormatter.referenceDate = refDate;
> calFormatter.referenceCalendarUnit = kCFCalendarUnitMonth;
>
> axisFixedInterval.labelFormatter = calFormatter;
>
> [dateFormatter release];
> ```

...this would give me a fixed distribution of 3-char months: [Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug]; for the 5 tick locations.

... from the plot_gallery_ios example.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `CPTAxisLabelingPolicyFixedInterval` labeling policy and a `labelFormatter` that creates month labels. Core Plot provides two different date formatters that might help: [CPTCalendarFormatter](http://core-plot.googlecode.com/hg/documentation/html/iOS/interface_c_p_t_calendar_formatter.html) and [CPTTimeFormatter](http://core-plot.googlecode.com/hg/documentation/html/iOS/interface_c_p_t_time_formatter.html). Which one you choose depends on how you're coding the date values in your dataset.